# Can not get access token from LinkedIn app. It is returning null in onActivityResult

Tags: android, sdk, linkedin-api

I am using linkedIn android sdk to sign in to app but cannot get the access token.

```
void startAutheniticate() {
    LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).init(this,
            buildScope(),
            new AuthListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthSuccess() {
                    // Saved AccessToken
                    AccessToken accessToken = LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getSession().getAccessToken();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {

                }
            }, true);
}

public static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS, Scope.W_SHARE);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Need the access token

[onActivityResult()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDgXT.png)

Comment: Have u added package name and hash key to linkedin developer account??

Comment: @LearnPainLess yes. Added

Comment: Have u generated hash key for same system which u r using to build app?

Comment: @LearnPainLess I have double checked package name and key hash settings in twitter account. Both debug and release keys are added. Same system is used to generate the key and the build.

Comment: I am wondering the setting up method : Using its OAuth 2  or importing the library

Comment: @Raju I am using Twitter Android SDK. It was working fine until 12th Jan 2019. But issue was reported on 14th Jan 2019

Comment: Excuse me. I guess we should focus on using Linkedin instead Twitter.

Comment: @Raju Yes my bad, sorry. I'm using **LinkedIn** Android SDK and it was working fine until 12th of Jan.

Comment: No worries. We may focus on this  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: And here is my question that I help you to raise

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212633/questions-on-revamping-the-linkedin-social-login-modules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have deprecated the v1 implementation but haven't yet updated their LinkedIn app (nor SDK) on Android, so the only solution available is to **use their JavaScript API to authenticate your applications via v2 implementation**.

Plus they said that developers had time until *March 1, 2019* but for some reason their Android application is now returning a `null` token *(starting from January 14, 2019)* if you try to use the LinkedIn SDK to authenticate your app

Here is the link of their updated v2 APIs for [Sign In with LinkedIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context)

Comment: Any update for this? When are they planning to make their app to work?